# CSS Animation swapping words

Tags: css, css-animations, styling

I want to copy this site: https://www.newkith.com/

The word that has to change is the word I marked beneath. I have tried some keyframes but I am not sure if this is possible with only css. I am a bit struggling to get it to work. Does someone know what css keyframe works the best? And do I need javacript?
[image]

```css
@keyframes swapWord {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        display: block;
    }


    100% {
        display: none;
        transform: translate(0%, -100%px);
         opacity: 0;
    }
}
.swapWordContainer {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.swapWord:nth-of-type(1) {
    animation: swapWord 0.6s;
    position: absolute;
    animation-delay: 4s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.swapWord:nth-of-type(2) {
    animation: swapWord 0.6s;
    animation-delay: 4s;
    position: absolute;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.swapWord:nth-of-type(3) {
    animation: swapWord 0.6s;
    animation-delay: 4s;
    position: absolute;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

```html
<div className="main-section-two">
  <div className="content-section-two">
    <h2>wij zijn experts in het <div className="swapWordContainer"><span className="swapWord">ontwerpen</span><span
          className="swapWord">bouwen</span><span className="swapWord">optimaliseren</span></div> van shopify stores.
    </h2>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can take a look here: https://codepen.io/yoannhel/pen/sJpDj
You basically create a list with items you wish and then you move the list up and down.

Comment: Yes great man thanks! That was what i needed!